# SWIFT 4 Detail Disclosure

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm new to programming and have just started with a deep dive into SWIFT and iOS development.

I've been stuck on a problem for over a few hours now and would be much obliged if someone could answer it. The assignment is bucket list and we have to built a basic app that uses two Table views (one dynamic and one static) to display a list of "bucket list" items using navigator controllers and modal display. In our first assignment, we were allowed to use two segues for the edit and save functionality but in the new assignment, we are being asked to refactor and use one segue with the hint being that we should use sender information. The present code uses two segues as I have not figured out how to refactor. As a note, we are using the accessory Detail Disclosure to bring up list items for edit. This is where I am getting stuck. From what I've been able to read, I understand the Disclosure Detail button is not a "true button" rather it is part of the index path. While I think I understand what needs to be done from a conceptual level, I am having a hell of a time actually solving the problem. Thanks in advance.

```
   import UIKit

     class BucketListViewController: UITableViewController, 
     AddItemTableViewControllerDelegate {
     var items = ["awesome","lessawesome","great"]
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected")
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWith indexPath: IndexPath) {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditItemSegue", sender: indexPath)
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "AddItemSegue"{
            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let addItemTableViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! AddItemTableViewController
            addItemTableViewController.delegate = self
        }else if segue.identifier == "EditItemSegue"{
            let navigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
            let AddItemTableViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! AddItemTableViewController
            AddItemTableViewController.delegate = self

            let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
            let item = items[indexPath.row]
            AddItemTableViewController.item = item
            AddItemTableViewController.indexPath = indexPath

        }
    }

    func cancelButtonPressed(by controller: AddItemTableViewController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func itemSaved(by controller: AddItemTableViewController, with text:String, at indexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

        if let ip = indexPath {
            items[ip.row] = text
        }else{
            items.append(text)
        }

        tableView.reloadData()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**AddItemTableViewControllerDelegate**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol AddItemTableViewControllerDelegate: class {

    func itemSaved(by controller: AddItemTableViewController, with text:String, at indexPath: NSIndexPath?)
    func cancelButtonPressed(by controller: AddItemTableViewController)
}
```

**AddItemTableViewController**

```
import UIKit

class AddItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    weak var delegate: AddItemTableViewControllerDelegate?
    var item: String?

    var indexPath: NSIndexPath?
    @IBOutlet weak var itemTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        delegate?.cancelButtonPressed(by: self)
    }


    @IBAction func saveButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let text = itemTextField.text!
        delegate?.itemSaved(by: self, with: text, at: indexPath)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        itemTextField.text = item

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by using one segue? Where is this segue going to?

Comment: Initially we were asked to use two segues from our main tableView controller to another. The first tableview controller contains the prototype list, display, and text bar. When the user clicks add, one segue takes the user to the second tableView via a modal where a new list item can be created.

Comment: This uses the AddItem segue route. One the main tabeView, we have inserted a Detail Disclosure accessory which uses the EditItem segue. When clicked the edit Item segues via modal to the posted item where the user can edit the post which is then put back in the list. The task now is to refactor the code so that only one segue is used which is where I'm getting stuck. In my code, the two segues are in the "override fun prepare". Thanks, Tj3n in advance :)